# How can i use corretly Latex notation via forEach function in vanilla JS?

Tags: foreach, value

I have array examples where i have example (ax^2 + 5x +1 = 0), example (ax^2 + 9x +9 = 0) etc.

I have following logic

```
const container = document.querySelector("#examples-container");
    examples.forEach((ex, i) => {
      const example = `
        <div class="card">
          <div class="example">
          ${ex.question}
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="toggle" onclick="toggle(${i})">
            Toggle
          </button>
          <div id="result_${i}" style="display:none" class="result">${ex.answer}</div>
        </div>`;
      container.innerHTML += example;
    });
```

Somehow is not working i get only string with array value and nothing else.
`<p>(ax^2 + 5x +1 = 0)</p>` Works well

Comment: I think this is a javascript/mathjax issue, and not really a LaTeX question... try web developer or coding.stackexchange